# Ionic/Cordova - What determines shown keyboard action key?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I can't seem to find anything about this on the web but depending on which screen of my app is shown when the user taps into an input box sometimes the keyboard shows a GO key and sometimes the RETURN key; ie shown at the bottom-right of the keyboard.

I'm building for both iOS and Android and ideally I'd like it to always show return key.

How can I ensure the keyboard always shows RETURN key?

Comment: If an `<input>` is enclosed by a `<form>` tag, the keyboard will have a `Go` key. If you have an `<input>` without a `<form>` tag surrounding it, it will just result in the `Return` key that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you change from `<input>` to `<textarea>` you will get the return key (which adds line breaks in the textarea) on iOS. I have not tested Android.